# Why memset() does not work properly when placed inside a loop body?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memset

Yesterday I programmed a small piece code in C++ which contains a loop and an array. In the program I need to reset the array every time the loop starts over. However, if I use

```
memset(sum,sizeof(sum),0);
```

Then the array won't be reset to all 0. For this program I used:

```
for (i=0;i<sizeof(sum)/sizeof(int);i++) sum[i]=0;
```

instead.

However, I think a loop is not as clear as a function, and it requires an additional variable, not to mention this is a million times uncool than the wizardry of memset() function. Could you guys enlighten me on this?

Comment: what is the `sum` variable type?

Comment: Did you verify that you didn't get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're actually writing the size of sum into the 0 first bytes.
You should be doing `memset(sum,0,sizeof(sum))` instead.

(In other words, the arguments are *target*, *data* and *length* and you provided data and length in the wrong order.)

Comment: Oops! Guess I haven't do C programming for too long... After all vectors are so handy that a man might forget what he had learned years before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ziyao:  If this post answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark to the left.

Comment: You might want to see Mark B's answer, as it's a more C++ -style solution to the problem.

Comment: @John Dibling: Thanks! I just did.

Answer (score 7):

This is C++ so do it the C++ way with `fill_n`.

`std::fill_n(&sum[0], sizeof(sum) / sizeof(sum[0]), 0);`

The reason your `memcpy` didn't work is because, as noted in other answers, you swapped the second and third arguments.

EDIT: `fill` and `fill_n` will work on anything that provides or can be treated as an output iterator. For standard containers like `vector` you can either pre-size the container or use `back_inserter` while for arrays you can use the form I indicated.

Comment: Wow, this is something I must memorize. Can fill_n work on arrays, or dies this function only work on vector/deque/etc.? Thank you for this answer!

Comment: @Ziyao:  Long story short, this can work on more than just the STL collection types.

Comment: It even works on IOstreams, e.g. on `std::cout` and `std::ofstream`, via `std::ostream_iterator<T>`

Answer (score 4):

```
memset(sum,sizeof(sum),0);
```

Wrong.

I think you wanted to write:

```
memset(sum,0, sizeof(sum));
```

The signature of `memset` function is this:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

And its [description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) is :

> Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value  (interpreted as an unsigned char).

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the parameters in the wrong order.

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/), the size parameter should be last:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of function **memset** is:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

So you need:

```
memset (sum, 0, sizeof(sum));
```